# how to construct a sql condition for not "created" two thursdays ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this condition in my sql for MySQL:

```
Created >= CONCAT( DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)) DAY), ' 00:00:00')
```

It is from at test to see if a user have participated since last thursday. Now the higher powers have decided, that it should change from weekly to every other week. That means the condition should change to check that Created is after two thursdays ago.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward using a `CASE` statement. For `WEEKDAY()` values of 0-3 (Monday - Thursday) subtract `WEEKDAY() + 11` days, and for `WEEKDAY()` values of 4-6 (Friday - Sunday) subtract `WEEKDAY() + 4 days`.

```
where created >= (
case
when (weekday(current_date()) <= 3) then 
  (current_date() - interval (weekday(current_date()) + 11) day)
else 
  (current_date() - interval (weekday(current_date()) + 4) day)
end 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Ike! Yes I was hoping it would be relatively easy for someone more experienced in sql.